# How to get rid off 'index.php' in my laravel 5.1 links on Virtual Host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm making a link to a controller's function resides in a sub directory of Controller directory named 'Admin'. When I make a link in the menu bar using following code:

```
{!! HTML::link('/admin', 'Admin') !!}  // www.property.com/admin
```

it doesn't work, but if I prefix '/admin' with 'index.php/admin' like this:

```
{!! HTML::link('index.php/admin', 'Admin') !!}  // www.property.com/index.php/admin
```

it works fine. What is the problem? How can I get rid off adding 'index.php' before each of my link like 'admini'?
**Note** I'm using virtual host named 'www.property.com' on Ubuntu 15.04.
here is my AdminController
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
?>
```

Here is my route file

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');

Route::resource('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController');
```

Here is the .htaccess file's code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is virtual host file code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin m.khuramj@live.com
    ServerName laravelproperty.com
    ServerAlias www.laravelproperty.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/property-project/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you load the mod_rewrite module in the Apache config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours, I've found the solution of this problem. Though a miner one but took a lot of time.

In my virtual host file add the the following code like given below:

```
    <Directory /var/www/property-project/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

you can compare the difference between this one and the code for virtual host give in the question above.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin m.khuramj@live.com
    ServerName laravelproperty.com
    ServerAlias www.laravelproperty.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/property-project/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/property-project/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, make sure the .htaccess in your public folder is there.

If this is not the case, create a .htaccess in the public folder with the following content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If it's still not working, make sure the mod_rewrite module in Apache is enabled :).

Comment: Thanks LeShadow! yes, I'm using apache and .htaccess is also there. I'm adding .htaccess code in the post. So you could check that